# Rails 4 - jQuery or Coffeescript to Show/Hide <div> based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm having trouble toggling divs based on a selection box in Rails 4.  I am trying to show certain form fields on a REQUEST form when a certain PRODUCT is selected. I have no jquery experience - this is what I have so far, but no bueno:

```
// assets/javascripts/requests.js.coffee

jQuery ->

    #//this handles product population based on category select and is working:

    $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()
    products = $('#request_product_id').html()
    emptyOption = $('<option />').attr('value', '');
    console.log(products)
    $('#request_category_id').change ->
        category = $('#request_category_id :selected').text()
        options = $(products).filter("optgroup[label='#{category}']").prepend(emptyOption).html()
        console.log(options)
        if options
            $('#request_product_id').html(options)
            $('#request_product_id').parent().show()
        else
            $('#request_product_id').empty()
            $('#request_product_id').parent().hide()


    #// this should handle <div> toggle based on product select, but nothing happens:

    $(document).ready ->
    $(".product").on "change", ->
    if $(this).val() is "6"
      $("#exit_employee").show()
      $("#new_employee").hide()
      $("#change_employee").hide()
    if $(this).val() is "7"
      $("#new_employee").show
      $("#exit_employee").hide()
      $("#change_employee").hide()
    if $(this).val() is "8"
      $("#change_employee").show
      $("#exit_employee").hide()
      $("#new_employee").hide()


    --------------
//.css

#exit_employee,
#new_employee,
#change_employee {
    display: none;
}

--------------

// _form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@request) do |f| %>

  <div class="field" id="category">
    <%= f.label :category_id, "Select a Category:" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.active.sorted, :id, :name, :include_blank => true ) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field" id="product">
    <%= f.label :product_id, "Select a Product/Service:" %>
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :product_id, Category.active.sorted, :products, :name, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>

  //THE ABOVE ALL WORKS -----  NOW....BASED ON PRODUCT SELECTED ABOVE, SHOW DIV BASED ON PRODUCT SELECTION


  <div>

    <div class="field" id="exit_employee"> 
        Product 6 Fields
    </div>

    <div class="field" id="new_employee">
        Product 7 Fields
    </div>

     <div class="field" id="change_employee">
        Product 8 Fields
     </div>

  </div>

 //ALWAYS SHOW REQUESTOR NOTE

    <div class="field" id="requestor_note">
        <%= f.label :requestor_note, "Please provide full details for your request:" %>
        <%= f.text_area :requestor_note %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: do you turn on turbo links?

Comment: Um - no?  What is that?

Comment: turbolinks is a new feature in Rails 4. It conflicts with $.ready and some more work needs to be done on to make $.ready work.

Comment: Oh, I don't think it's enabled, unless it's by default.  This is for a selection list, not a link, does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You are using coffeescript rather than javascript in your `<script>` tag, but you are specifying `<script type="text/javascript">`.

You may be able to change this to coffeescript, i.e. `<script type="text/coffeescript">`.  See [the explanation on coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts).

A better practice would be to enable the asset pipeline in your rails project, remove the `<script>` tags from the view and put the coffeescript in a file under `app/assets/javascripts`.  See [the rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for more details.

Another tip is to enable devtools in your browser and look at the javascript console.  This is where javascript error messages are written, including JS syntax errors.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed script tag to /coffeescript, but no change.  And, I have the asset pipeline enabled and an existing coffeescript file  - I just don't know how to add the new function to it (syntax). I'll run a debug in IE to see what's up. Thanks - I'll keep digging.

Comment: Moved my script to the assets/javascripts/requests.js.coffee file.  No errors in debug on IE, but nothing happens when I select a product. :(

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of your indentation. In coffeescript indentation is important in some case

```
$(document).ready ->
$(".product").on "change", ->
if $(this).val() is "6"
  $("#exit_employee").show()
  $("#new_employee").hide()
  $("#change_employee").hide()
if $(this).val() is "7"
  $("#new_employee").show
  $("#exit_employee").hide()
  $("#change_employee").hide()
if $(this).val() is "8"
  $("#change_employee").show
  $("#exit_employee").hide()
  $("#new_employee").hide()
```

should be

```
$(document).ready ->
  $(".product").on "change", ->
  if $(this).val() is "6"
    $("#exit_employee").show()
    $("#new_employee").hide()
    $("#change_employee").hide()
  if $(this).val() is "7"
    $("#new_employee").show
    $("#exit_employee").hide()
    $("#change_employee").hide()
  if $(this).val() is "8"
    $("#change_employee").show
    $("#exit_employee").hide()
    $("#new_employee").hide()
```